# Uncorrected pairwise p-values for one-way ANOVA?

Tags: r, anova, self-study, multiple-comparisons

I'm performing a relatively simple one-way ANOVA as part of a class exercise. I'd like to get pairwise uncorrected p-values out of R, so I can do a sequential FDR test in another package (I realize there are FDR packages in R as well). I've set up my ANOVA as shown below, and it works fine, produces results, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the raw, uncorrected p-values back. Ultimately, I'd like to do the pairwise tests for both FDR and sequential Bonferroni in R, but this seems like a first step.

It looks like `pairwiseCI` or `multcomp` might get me where I'm trying to go, but I'm having a difficult time figuring out which will do what I'm looking for.

```
R> head(d10)
  time  breed
1 27.4 type.A
2 18.3 type.A
3 24.3 type.B
4 19.6 type.B
5 21.6 type.C
6 30.3 type.D

a10 <- aov(time~breed,data=d10)

# reports the overall significance, but nothing on the pairs  
summary(a10)

# reports corrected values only
TukeyHSD(a10)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the `multcomp` package, see the help page for `glht`; you want to use the `"Tukey"` option; this does not actually use the Tukey correction, it just sets up all pairwise comparisons.  In the example section there's an example that does exactly what you want.

This calculates the estimates and se's for each comparison but doesn't do p-values; for that you need `summary.glht`; on the help page for that, notice in particular the `test` parameter, that allows you to set the actual test that is run.  For doing multiply-adjusted p-values, you use the `adjusted` function for this parameter, and to not multiply-adjust, you use `test=adjusted("none")` (which isn't mention specifically in the help page, though it does say it takes any of the methods in `p.adjust`, which is where you'd find `none`.)

You can also compute the estimates and se's by hand using matrix multiplication, and then get the p-values however you want; this is what the `glht` function is doing behind the scenes.  To get the matrices you need to start you'd use `coef` and `vcov`.

I didn't put complete code as you say it's for a class project (thanks for being honest, by the way!) and the policy here is to provide helpful hints but not solutions.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer! Re: homework; this is a graduate course and this work isn't being turned in, I know how to perform the same in the class-used JMP but would like to stick to R as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the update about the homework status.  If you need more specific help, let us know.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `pairwise.t.test()` with one of the available options for multiple comparison correction in the `p.adjust.method=` argument; see `help(p.adjust)` for more information on the available option for single-step and step-down methods (e.g., `BH` for FDR or `bonf` for Bonferroni). Of note, you can directly give `p.adjust()` a vector of raw p-values and it will give you the corrected p-values.

So, I would suggest to run something like

```
pairwise.t.test(time, breed, p.adjust.method ="none")  # uncorrected p-value
pairwise.t.test(time, breed, p.adjust.method ="bonf")  # Bonferroni p-value
```

The first command gives you t-test-based p-values without controlling for FWER or FDR. You can then use whatever command you like to get corrected p-values.

Comment: By the name, one might think it computes each pairwise t test separately (I did, anyway), but it actually uses the pooled SD by default, so the result is the same as using the anova result.

Comment: @Aaron You're right, it uses pooled SD by default, but it can be disabled. We could also construct every contrast we want with simple algebra. I like your response btw (+1).

Answer (score 2):

```
library(multcomp)
df = mtcars
df$am = as.factor(df$am)
m1 <- aov(mpg ~ am, data= df)
ht = glht(m1, linfct = mcp(am = "Tukey"))
summary(ht, test = adjusted("none"))
# Linear Hypotheses:
#            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
# 1 - 0 == 0    7.245      1.764   4.106 0.000285 ***
```